# Newbie "Cast To" Object in UE4

Tags: casting, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have blueprint for spawning zombies with a parameter 'NumOfZombies".
In Zombie's blueprint when health = 0 I want to -1 to NumOfZombies.

I use Cast To BP_SpawnPoint to get to NumOfZombies parameter but I don't know what to set to object.

When I cast to my character I attach "get player character" but reffering to other blueprints seems to me a bit confusing.

Comment: Be more specific, take a screenshot for the blueprints

Comment: I have 1 blueprint "SpawnPoint" for spawning Zombie enemies.
That BP has parameter "NumOfZombies".
2nd blueprint "Zombie" is for his animations, AI etc. in wchich I want to reffer to BP 1 "SpawnPoint" 's parameter NumOfZombies.
To do so I use "Cast To SpawnPoint".
On the left side of this box you have to set object.
I don't know what to set to it to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a object that it might be a SpawnPoint. When you use *'cast to something'* node you want to check whether that object is of the type you want.

So, if you want to keep NumOfZombies parameter you have to create in your Zombie blueprint a variable that is of the type of the class "BP_SpawnPoint". Then you keep that variable and cast to BP_SpawnPoint, and finally get your parameter.